# Sequential Processing of Files in IIB v9

Tags: message, broker

Environment:IIB9 broker on windows
SFTP server is on windows

We have requirements to process a batch of files generated by backend system in sequential order (i.e FIFO). A batch can have multiple files.
All the files are placed in the IIB source directory from where FileInputNode is polling using move command.

I Want to know if FileInputNode is capable of picking up files in the order they were created by backend system.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Below is the extract from help contents where in it says that FileInput node reads the file in the order they were created by default (oldest are picked up first).

> **How the broker reads a file at the start of a flow**
>
> The FileInput node processes messages that are read from files. The
>   FileInput node searches a specified input directory (in the file
>   system that is attached to the broker) for files that match specified
>   criteria. The node can also recursively search the input directory's
>   subdirectories.
>
> Files that meet the criteria are processed in age order, that is the
>   oldest files are processed first regardless of where they appear in
>   the directory structure

.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac55280_.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can loop in your messageflow and set the filepath of the file you want to load, one at a time. Feel free to ask for information if needed.

For the order, I have to check(you can still call a java node that will list the files in the order you want)

Regards